# Phonegap: How to detect android application is running in development mode

Tags: android, cordova, configuration

I need to distinguish if my Phonegap Android app is running

A) in emulator or in phone via USB debug mode

B) normally in phone

Is it even possible? Do you know any trick? I need this for automatic configuration switching between devel and prod... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, some platforms allow package introspection at runtime.

On Android, the native library is the [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html), linked to docs. Whether or not you can get the info you need from the interface will (hopefully) be documented

There is currently no plugin or api to access this information from the phonegap javascript environment. However, this would be simple to implement.

I might be willing to put together such a plugin. It would be relatively simple and potentially useful. Or I could help you through the process.

**EDIT**
yes, this information is available, here is a snippet:

```
if ((ctx.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
    ctx.getPackageName(), 0).applicationInfo.flags & 
    ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0) {
    //Debug and development mode
    BASE_SERVICE_URL = "http://qa.example.com";
}
```

I found the code above on the [MOBIARCH BLOG](http://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/detecting-debug-and-release-builds-in-ios-and-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Ace plugin](http://microsoft.github.io/ace/), you can invoke arbitrary APIs. So the code from Lorenzo can be written in your JavaScript as follows:

```
var ctx = ace.android.getContext();
ctx.invoke("getPackageManager", function (pm) {
    ctx.invoke("getPackageName", function (name) {
        pm.invoke("getPackageInfo", name, 0, function (info) {
            info.getField("applicationInfo", function (appInfo) {
                ace.NativeObject.getField("android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo", "FLAG_DEBUGGABLE", function(DEBUGGABLE) {
                    appInfo.getField("flags", function (flags) {
                        if (flags & DEBUGGABLE != 0) {
                            // Debug and development mode
                            BASE_SERVICE_URL = "http://qa.example.com";
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```